# What is the symbol "-" called?

Tags: puntuación, solicitud-de-término

What do you call dash in Spanish? I mean this symbol: `-`.

Suggesions: guion, guión, raya.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is a **guion** or **guión**.

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas says on [guion](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=guion):

> guion<sup>2</sup> o guión. Este signo ortográfico (`-`) no debe confundirse con la raya (`—`). Ambos se representan por medio de un trazo horizontal, pero el guion es de una longitud sensiblemente menor que la de la raya (→ raya). Para la doble acentuación de esta palabra, → guion1 o guión. El guion se usa en los casos siguientes (...)

You may be also surprised by the fact that it can or cannot use accent. This is why:

> en la última edición de la Ortografía académica (1999) se establece que toda combinación de vocal cerrada átona y abierta tónica se considere diptongo a efectos de acentuación gráfica. Por ello, en guion y otras palabras en la misma situación, como ion, muon, pion, prion, Ruan, Sion y truhan, se da preferencia a la grafía sin tilde, aunque se permite que aquellos hablantes que pronuncien estas voces en dos sílabas puedan seguir tildándolas

Comment: As of the 2010 Orthography, IIRC, it's only without, regardless of whether one pronounces it with one or two syllables.

Comment: I can testify that in Chile *raya* used to be common and still exists. It is receding due to the fact that some consider it rude since it also colloquially means intergluteal cleft. Anyway, just as you say, in the DLE the use of [raya](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VEnqyiQ|VEqi7AW) as a symbol is reserved for the longer line (—).

Comment: @guifa What's the RAE's stance on this? Having no graphic accent mark kinda flies in the face of accentuation rules. I'll be honest, I'm a little irked by this :P

Comment: @JATerroba the rationale given is that, regardless whether you write *guion* or *guión*, the O is stressed.  The only question is whether there is a diphthong or a hiatus.  Given that we don't write *fiár* (despite most people pronouncing *fi-AR*) or enviár (to show the I and A are on separate syllables), it's odd to make an exception for words like *guion*.  The reality is that there are many instances in Spanish of unstressed weak vowels combined with un(stressed) strong vowels that can alternate relatively freely between hiatus and diphthong, and none get marked.

Comment: The full discussion is in the Ortografía pp. 223-227 ( http://www.rae.es/recursos/ortografia/ortografia-2010 ).  If you were writing poetry or similar and wanted to strongly reflect the existence of the hiatus, you could write *guïon*, which is already commonly used in poetry for words like *süave* or *crüel* to indicate su-A-ve and cru-EL, respectively, rather than SUA-ve and CRUEL.

Comment: This is the first I hear of any of this. I do have a rebuttal on the *fiar* and *enviar* remarks. No matter if there's a diphthong or not, they are *agudas* (stress in the last syllable) and end in r, therefore, no tilde, at least as far as the rules were taught to me, my schooling on Spanish ended in grade school, after that it's just life experience :)  Is there a reason you used diaeresis in *cruel* and *suave*? 
This is all very interesting to me, thanks for humoring me on these questions.

Comment: @JaTerroba right, *guion* and *guión*, both are by definition *palabras agudas* and will have the stress on the O (compare to *video/vídeo*, where a different vowel is stressed entirely, and both forms still coexist). Since unstressed hiatuses are not marked anywhere else in Spanish, that rule has been applied to words that could be 1 or 2 syllables.  On the dieresis...  *suave* normally is two syllables *SWA-be*, but very frequently in poetry it is treated as three (*su-A-be*) and is written with a dieresis, *süave* to indicate the broken diphthong.  The A is still the stressed vowel, though.